# Feature request: Ignore post

Tags: feature-request

There are so many questions that are of no interest and/or have already been answered. It would be nice to be able to filter to those out of personal view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using [favorite tags](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/interesting-topics) and [search parameters](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/searching). For example:

- [Newest questions with one of your favorite tags that do not have an upvoted or accepted answer](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine%20isanswered%3ano%20hasaccepted%3ano%20closed%3ano)
- [Newest questions with one of your favorite tags that have no answers at all](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine%20answers%3a0%20closed%3ano)

Closed questions are excluded from both of the above searches. One can also filter out downvoted questions by adding the parameter `score:0..` (with two dots after zero).